# Curling the page on mediatemple(dv)?

Tags: curl, php

I have a WordPress install on a dedicated virtual sever with mediatemple. I am also using a web service call idxbroker that allows user to search mls listings from my site at http://valenciateam.com. The web service instructs me to place php tags:

```
<?php idx_start ?>
```

and

```
<?php idx_stop ?>
```

into the theme files to dynamically integrate my wordpress design with the pages that it creates.

My problem is that the tags seem to echo an error at the top of the page that informs me that: There was a problem curling the page, please make sure your server allows curling.

I'm guessing that I would need to edit the php.ini file on my server but I have no clue what where to begin making the server "allow page curling".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mediatemple (dv) servers come with curl pre-loaded, but to use php's curl functionality you must have the php extension loaded in php.ini

You can check if it is enabled by creating a script like the following and viewing its output in the browser:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If the curl extension is loaded then there will be an entry in the `phpinfo()` output titled "curl"

If there isn't, you need to edit your php.ini file. You should have this line somewhere (make sure it's not commented out) ...

```
extension=php_curl.so
```

Afterwards, restart apache. You should be able to do this on a mediatemple dv to restart apache:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

After apache comes back online, check the phpinfo() output again for the "curl" section. This should solve the most likely cause of your problem.

Comment: No prob -- Ive been working with mediatemple dv servers for a couple of years and have come across most of the usual issues by now :)